# Price Difference Question. Unable to derive 3rd equation

Tags: recreational-mathematics

A man buys Rs.7 apples.
When after a few days the price of the apple goes down by Rs.2, he buys 6 more apples.

Both the amounts were in whole numbers, were two digits and has the same digits.

Find how many apples could be bought for Rs.144.

The equations I could find was :

```
i)  10a + b = 7x
ii) 10b + a = 6(x-2)
```

Where:

- x : cost/apple for trans a
- x-2 : cost/apple for trans b
- 10a+b : trans a total
- 10b+a : trans b total

There are three variables, how do I derive the third equation ?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a third equation per se, but another constraint is obtained from the proviso that all quantities (and therefore $a$ and $b$) are integers.  If you subtract Equation (ii) from Equation (i), you obtain

$$
9a-9b = x+12
$$

or

$$
9(a-b) = x+12
$$

We know from this that $x+12$ is divisible by $9$, so $x$ could be $6$, $15$, $24$, etc.  At this point, we introduce the condition that the total costs in both cases were two-digit quantities.  If $x$ were $15$ or more, the seven original apples would cost $105$ or more, violating the condition.  Therefore, $x = 6$.